# Avoid Python Script Crash After Lost Connection

Tags: python, debian

I have a simple python script recovering a string data from serial port.
Then using some lines of code I store each parameter in a mongo database in local host.

I run the script sucessfully in debian 10, but when I force to drop the database server in local host localhost:27017 , the script fail.

How can I avoid the script crash after connection with database is lost? I would like the script follow alive forever searching the serial data.

```
import serial
import pymongo
import ...
....

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["databasename"]
mycol = mydb["collection"]

ser = serial.Serial('COM9', 9600, timeout=1)

def getSerial():

        data_raw=ser.read(25)

        if len(data_raw) > 23 and data_raw[0] == 83 :
                        measure = {
                                "time": data_raw[1:6],
                                "date": data_raw[6:14],
                                "param1": data_raw[14:18],
                                "param2": data_raw[18:22],
                                "created_at": datetime.datetime.now(),
                        }
                        x = mycol.insert_one(measure)

while True:
        getSerial()
```

Comment: Find out what exception is being thrown. And then "handle" it. Which would probably involve re-establishing connection with mongo, then re-creating the database

Comment: Okay i will search about "handle" on linux

Comment: wrap the insert_one in a try ... exception;

Comment: @asterix: Read [the-try-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement)